# How to supply parameters to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Friends i am making a windows form application in which i have created a stored procedure in sql-server-2008 , then created a external class in windows form like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Jain_milan.Common
{
   public class Personal
    {
        string name, fathername, mothername, familyhead, dateofbirth,educationlvl, education, blood, gotra, panth, marrital;

        public string Educationlvl
        {
           get { return educationlvl; }
           set { educationlvl = value; }
        }

        public string Panth
        {
            get { return panth; }
            set { panth = value; }
        }

        public string Gotra
        {
            get { return gotra; }
            set { gotra = value; }
        }

        public string Blood
        {
            get { return blood; }
            set { blood = value; }
        }

        public string Education
        {
            get { return education; }
            set { education = value; }
        }

        public string DateOfBirth
        {
            get { return dateofbirth; }
            set { dateofbirth = value; }
        }

        public string FamilyHead
        {
            get { return familyhead; }
            set { familyhead = value; }
        }

        public string MotherName
        {
            get { return mothername; }
            set { mothername = value; }
        }

        public string FatherName
        {
            get { return fathername; }
            set { fathername = value; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string Marrital
        {
            get { return marrital; }
            set { marrital = value; }
        }

    }

}
```

where i have created get set function for all the paramerets 
In another external class i define all the stored procedure like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Jain_milan.DataAction
{
    public enum InsertStoredProcedure
    {
        insertpersonal,
        insertressicontact,
        insertoccupcontact,
        insertspouse,
        insert1children,
        insert2children,
        insert3children,
        insert4children,
        insert5children
    }
}
```

After to insert it into the database i again created a seprate class and pass the parameters like this

```
  public class InsertAction
    {
       public bool Insertpersonal(Personal per)
       {
               SqlCommand cmd = Database.GetConnection().CreateCommand();
               cmd.CommandText=InsertStoredProcedure.insertpersonal.ToString();
               cmd.CommandType= CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name",per.Name));
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FatherName",per.FatherName));
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MotherName",per.MotherName));
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FamilyHead",per.FamilyHead));
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateOfBirth",per.DateOfBirth));
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EducationLevel", per.Educationlvl));
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Education",per.Education));
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Blood",per.Blood));
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Gotra",per.Gotra));
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Panth",per.Panth));
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Marrital",per.Marrital));
               bool ans = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
               cmd.Dispose();
               Database.CloseConnection();
               return ans;
           }}
```

then on submit button i have done the coding for submit action ....

```
  private void submit_addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //personal data insert
                Personal per = new Personal();
                per.Name = nametxt.Text;
                per.FatherName = f_nametxt.Text;
                per.MotherName = m_nametxt.Text;
                per.Gotra = gotra_txt.Text;
                per.Panth = panthcb.Text;
                per.FamilyHead = fhntext.Text;
                per.Educationlvl = edulvlcb.Text;
                per.Education = educb.Text;
                per.Blood = bloodcb.Text;
                per.Marrital = MarritalStatus;
                per.DateOfBirth = (day + '/' + month + '/' + year).ToString();
                if (new InsertAction().Insertpersonal(per))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Personal Insertion Happen ");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Personal Insertion does not Happen ");
                }
}}
```

On running the program it is showing the error that

> Procedure or function 'insertpersonal' expects parameter '@educationlvl' which was not supplied

But i have supplied it like all other parameter then whats the problem occurring .....
Please solve this.Please Please Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a naming problem.  Try changing:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EducationLevel", per.Educationlvl));
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EducationLvl", per.Educationlvl));
```

Edit, for Marrital issue:

Try changing:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Marrital",per.Marrital));
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Marrital", per.Marrital ?? DBNull.Value));
```

The equivalent of C# `null` for a database is `DBNull.Value`.  You can't pass in a C# `null` to a database, it doesn't like it.  So, what you do is check if the value that you're wanting to send in is `null`.  If it is, send in `DBNull.Value` instead.  That's what `per.Marrital ?? DBNull.Value` does.  It's the same as doing this, but in a much shorter syntax:

```
object marritalValue = per.Marrital;
if(marritalValue == null)
    marritalValue = DBNull.Value
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Marrital", marritalValue ));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: hey, now it is giving same msg for marrital

Comment: its name is same.. so problem with naming

Comment: Check your stored procedure - what is it looking for?  I'm going to guess it's looking for "marital" (one r) (what's the exact error it's telling you?).

Comment: no dear there is no problem with 'r' see the above code, even i have checked it in sql-server-2008

Comment: Procedure or function 'insertpersonal' expects parameter '@marrital' which was not supplied

Comment: Is the value you're passing in for per.Marrital null?

Comment: Try setting that to a specific value, else pass in DBNull.Value.  I'll edit my post to show an example.

Comment: thank you sir it worked now will you please explain the meaning of ??DBNull...........Please

Comment: Added explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter has to be with the same name `@educationlvl` is not the same as `@EducationLevel`. Hope this helps.